# Child's height restricted to parent's remaining space

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid-layout

How should I use CSS3 to set the scrollbox class to adjust its height to all remaining space of its parent. The scrollbox should not change its parent's height even if the scrollbox content is very long. In such a situation the scrollbox should show scrollbars. Is it possible?

```css
div {
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: white;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid: 20vw 1fr / 20vh 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "top-left main""bottom-left  main";
  grid-row-gap: 4px;
  grid-column-gap: 4px;
}
.top-left {
  grid-area: top-left;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.bottom-left {
  grid-area: bottom-left;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: lightpink;
}
.scrollbox {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="top-left">
    Top-Left
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-left">
    Bottom-Left
    <div class="scrollbox">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 2000 2000">
        <circle cx="1000" cy="1000" r="1000" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    Main
    <div class="scrollbox">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 2000 2000">
        <circle cx="1000" cy="1000" r="1000" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "adjust its height to all remaining space of its parent" you are referring to the body's height of `100vh`, the `scrollbox` classes are nor the real issue. What you may want is to restrict all the direct children of the body to a specific height, which when summed up, is less than the body's height.

I.e. if the body has 3 children, each children's height would be 100/3 units, so you'd only need something like this:

```
body>*{
  max-height: 33.33333333vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

The overflow property adds the vertical scrollbars you wanted.
In order to make sure that only the `scrollbox` classes are to have specific heights and those scrollbars then you can reference them in a similar way:

```
body>*>.scrollbox {
  max-height: 30vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

However, I wonder why you are giving the body that height? `vh` is a [particular unit](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units), and 100vh in the body tag is the same as writing 100%:

> With vw/vh, we can size elements to be relative to the size of the viewport. The vw/vh units are interesting in that **1 unit reflects 1/100th the width of the viewport**. To make an element the full width of the viewport, for example, you'd set it to width:100vw.

Here's your snippet though:

```css
div {margin: 0;border-radius: 12px;padding: 6px;background-color: white;}
body {margin: 0px;width: auto;height: 100vh;display: grid;grid: 20vw 1fr / 20vh 1fr;grid-template-areas: "top-left main""bottom-left  main";grid-row-gap: 4px;grid-column-gap: 4px;}
.top-left {grid-area: top-left;background-color: lightblue;}
.bottom-left {grid-area: bottom-left;background-color: lightgreen;}
.main {grid-area: main;background-color: lightpink;}
.scrollbox {
  background-color: white;
}
body>*>.scrollbox {
  max-height: 30vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="top-left">
    Top-Left
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-left">
    Bottom-Left
    <div class="scrollbox">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 2000 2000">
        <circle cx="1000" cy="1000" r="1000" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    Main
    <div class="scrollbox">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 2000 2000">
        <circle cx="1000" cy="1000" r="1000" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I am a newbie so I don't know proper terminology, units, etc. Sorry for that.

Comment: What I want to achieve? I just want both white divs (scrollboxes) to be persistently aligned to whole free space of green (Bottom-Left) and pink (Main) divs.

Comment: @PiotrAntoniak I was also not very familiar with `vh`, it's a useful unit for different viewports (responsive design). `max-height` allows you to restrict the inner content's height to a specific space, but if you really want them to stay in the same place even if they're smaller than max-height, you can use `height`.

Comment: I would try to use both. The height to set the height of the scrollbox and max-height to prevent scrollbox expanding in case of a long content). But the problem is how to set them properly? I tried 100%, 100vh, etc. but it does not work as I expect.

Comment: @PiotrAntoniak do you really want to use 100% or 100vh in the body? My point is, since you want to use all the space of that page, you just need to divide 100 by the number of scrollboxes you want to place on there. This value will be the height of each scrollbox (subtract the space of other elements in that page).